# JLabels in JPanel, on runtime new label contains previous labels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

The problem is that on runtime when new label is created it displays on the JPanel but containing the label created before.

The code converts text to bits offprint, like "HI" converts to

[image]

but when another text is converted like "OK" the bits label shows both "HI" and "OK"

This is the code from the MouseHandler class in mouseClicked method

```
 //Convert button is clicked.
    if(event.getSource().equals(getButton1Tab2()))
    {
        //convert text to image.
        TextOverlay textOverlay = new TextOverlay(getTextArea1Tab2().getText());

        //save image bits in ArrayList.
        for(int i=0; i<textOverlay.imageBits.length;i++)
        {
            //add new line after printing each line of bits (bit line length = image width)
            if(i!=0 && (i%Control.valves==0)){setBitsString(getBitsString().append("<br />"));}

            //add bit to ArrayList
            setBitsString(getBitsString().append(textOverlay.imageBits[i]));
        }
        //add new label to ArrayList of labels, the new label is bits offprint of the text's image.
        labelsArray.add(new JLabel("<html>"+getBitsString()+"</html>"));

        labelsArray.get(labelsArray.size()-1).addMouseListener(this);
        //show binary equivalent on screen
        panel2Tab2.add(labelsArray.get(labelsArray.size()-1));
        panel2Tab2.validate();
        panel2Tab2.repaint();
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please clarify your problem some more for us. At least for me your problem is very unclear. As an aside, you should not be adding MouseListeners to JButtons but rather ActionListeners. The MouseListener behavior is inadequate for a button.

Comment: Do you ever *remove* the old labels from the panel? Consider writing `panel2Tab2.removeAll()` before you add the new labels

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to remove old labels I just want the new ones not to duplicate the previous ones. so clearing the bitsString is the answer. @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I will use ActionListeners thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever `getBitsString()` returns, you always append to it, but you never clear it. You should clear it first when you want to change its content.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this line:

```
if(i!=0 && (i%Control.valves==0)){setBitsString(getBitsString().append("<br />")
```

You append the new bit string and then you add the result of getBitsString() to your label.